# java Null pointer Exception on fetching JSON

Tags: java, android, json

this is my code it throws java null pointer exception on fetching json from url.i have given the internet permission in android manifest and now fetch url in new thread as it does not allow network activities in main threaed

```
 package com.example.usa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class Home extends Activity {
    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";


    JSONArray contacts = null;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        final JSONObject json = null ;
        // getting JSON string from URL
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {



            @Override
            public void run() {

                Thread thread = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while(true) {
                                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                                sleep(1000);

                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                thread.start();




                //
                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);






       // JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);









new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {



            @Override
            public void run() {

                 try {
                        // Getting Array of Contacts
                        contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                            String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                            String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                            String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                            String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                            /////////////////////////// 
                            Log.w("ID",id);
                            Log.w("Name",name);
                            Log.w("Email",email);
                            Log.w("Gender",gender);
                            Log.w("mobile",mobile);
                            Log.w("home",home);
                            Log.w("office",office);
                            Log.w("address",address);

                            ///////////////////
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                            map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            contactList.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                //
                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

this is the stack trace

```
10-04 06:39:24.830: D/dalvikvm(777): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15K, 4% free 4156K/4288K, paused 42ms, total 45ms
10-04 06:39:24.850: I/dalvikvm-heap(777): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.635MB for 1536016-byte allocation
10-04 06:39:25.040: D/dalvikvm(777): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5655K/5792K, paused 180ms, total 180ms
10-04 06:39:30.280: D/AndroidRuntime(777): Shutting down VM
10-04 06:39:30.280: W/dalvikvm(777): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.example.usa.Home$2.run(Home.java:105)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-04 06:39:30.290: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 06:39:34.957: D/dalvikvm(777): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 261K, 6% free 6445K/6824K, paused 81ms, total 98ms
10-04 06:40:00.868: D/dalvikvm(777): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2688K, 36% free 5075K/7880K, paused 39ms, total 43ms
10-04 06:44:25.888: I/Process(777): Sending signal. PID: 777 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post full stack trace to determine location and cause of NPE

Comment: I would suggest you to use GSON libray for this which will parse this JSON in one line.

Comment: Can you please Explain how?

Comment: I still wonder why you haven't used `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

but you also have a method variable json, which I think you are intending to use later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

In the first thread you are retreiving data from URL and parsing it to json, soon after first thread, you are trying to retrieve data from JSON object, ***which most probably don't have any data because it is still busy in retrieving data.***

So it is not a good idea. `Retrieve and get data from JSON array in the same thread. This will save you alot of trouble.`

Second you are storing the json parsed data in a ***local json object in the first thread instead of the global one*** and trying to use the null json object to get TAG_CONTACT data. *This is causing NULL Pointer Exception*

Comment: Please can u explain how to get data from json in another thread really cant get it to work

Comment: You will have to parse data to json and get data from json array in the same thread unless the threads are synchronized which is quite curbersome for beginners. In this case you are parsing in one thread and get data from array in another thread. So move json parsing code in the thread in which you are getting data from json array

Comment: Thanku so much @Umer Farooq